# d3.geo.tile limiting zoomable map to make street view zoom scale smaller

Tags: javascript, d3.js, openstreetmap, d3.geo

I've been following this D3 implementation of a [zoomable map tiles](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797) and [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/6147081) to create a street view map of paths of a certain city. I have loaded the map but I keep running into issues with adding svg paths such as:

- most paths disappearing in some computed stroke-widths (separate SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49283086/d3-geo-tile-point-to-point-path-not-showing-for-varying-widths))
- mouseover & mouseout events are not triggered anymore while zoomed in (possibly due to stroke-widths as well)

These happens usually if the paths are to short ie a street-to-street path. But when I create a path from one country to another, it works. However, this is not what I need.

Reading around, I think the problem is that zooming in into a street view level sets the scale too large for the dynamically adjusting svg elements (ex. 4.47035e-08 stroke width) since the view starts at a world view level. Is there a way to limit the initial view to a country/city level so that the scale would not be as large?

Or is there another way to achieve this? Viewport? Viewbox? Any help is greatly appreciated!